# sed: can't read : No such file or directory

Tags: search, replace, sed

I am running the following command:

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec sed "s/foo/bar/g" {} \;
```

where the file structure looks like this:

```
./two/three.html
./two/two.html
./two/one.html
./three/three.html
./three/two.html
./three/one.html
./one/three.html
./one/two.html
./one/one.html
```

However, sed comes back saying the files could not be found, even though these two commands work fine on their own (i.e. I can run a find by itself, and I can run sed by itself fine).

I had a peer look at it with me, and he was stumped also.  I ended up going a different route, but I'd still like to know what exactly is going wrong here.

Comment: What if you remove the `-print` part? To me it looks unnecessary.

Comment: `print` will print the name of the file before `sed` does the action. Probably something that OP wants.

Comment: assuming you're really using `sed -i` to "save In-place", else where is the output going in your example. I think @fedorqui is onto something. Good luck.

Comment: I added -print to make sure it was hitting the files.  When I remove it, I get the same results.

Comment: Possibly the unquoted braces are a problem. Try: `-exec sed 's/foo/bar/g' '{}' \;`

Comment: To wrap up the question, you might as well post an answer, so others can benefit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to glenn jackman for the advice:

I needed to place quotes around the brackets as such:

```
-exec sed "s/foo/bar/g" '{}' \;
```

Rather than how I initially posted it.