# Sed gives: sed: can't read : No such file or directory

Tags: bash, sed, quoting, gnu-sed

I have the following `bash` script which repeats for each image found. It needs to iterated over all *html*, *css* and *js* files, and replace all occurrences of an image within that file.

```
 for image in app/www/images-theme-dark/*.png
    do
        echo "installing icon" $image

        # extract filename from iconpath
        iconfile=$(basename $image)
        iconPath="images/"$(basename $image)

        # replace paths in all files containing icon paths
        find app/www -type f \( -name "*.html" -or -name "*.css" -or -name "*.js" \
                            -or -name "*.appcache" \)  \
            -exec sed -i '' -e 's|$iconPath|images-theme-dark/$iconfile|g' "{}" \;

    done
```

However when I run the script `sed` gives:

`sed: can't read : No such file or directory`

On StackOverflow I've found [sed: can't read : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716187/sed-cant-read-no-such-file-or-directory) But I already had quotes around `{}`

When I echo the `sed` command and and execute it on the command line manually there is no error.

I am using GNU sed v4.2.2 on Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)

Does someone see what could be wrong here?

Comment: Btw: see: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: What is that `''` after `sed -i`?

Comment: @melpomene it prevents sed to create a backup file and replaces directly in the file instead

Comment: Please add OS and sed version to your question.

Comment: Replace `-i ''` by `-i`. For your next problem see my first comment.

Comment: Dear Osi, Melpomene asked you a question with the intention that you will consider it carefully, for example by reading the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/sed.1.html). You _think_ that `-i ''` "prevents sed to create a backup file and replaces directly in the file instead", but have your actually _checked_ that what you think is correct? Hint: you are wrong.

Comment: @AlexP to be honest I didn't I took it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486667/sed-without-backup-file thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @osi: syntax of `-i` is one difference between GNU sed and sed from mac os.

Comment: @osi: `-i` means _in-place_, that is, edit in the file directly. `-i ''` means _edit in place a file whose name is the empty string_. Since probably you don't actually have a file whose name is the empty string, `sed` complains that it cannot read it.

Comment: @Yunnosh: [The syntax](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/sed.1.html) requires the suffix of the backup copy immediately after `-i`, not as a separate argument. For example, `sed -i.bak` will edit a file in place and make a backup by appending `.bak`. A separate argument is taken as the name of a file to edit. Tested with GNU `sed` 4.2.2.

Comment: @AlexP You are right (blushing). Can't recreate what I tested. Thanks. One of the things which got me off track is that the script, with `-e`, can be between file names. Now I think your comment should be an answer; and be voted up.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

(*Compiling an answer from comments, the know-how is by melpomene and AlexP.*)

What is that `''` after `sed -i`?

`-i` means in-place, that is, edit in the file directly.
`-i ''`  means edit in place a file whose name is the empty string.
Since there probably is no file whose name is the empty string, sed complains that it cannot read it.

Note 1 **platform dependency**:
The syntax of `-i` is one difference between GNU sed and sed from mac os.

Note 2 **"usual" order of arguments**:
The `-e` switch to indicate the sed code allows having it in between file names.
This is a trap (in which I for example got caught embarassingly), by making you trip over your expectations of what you find where in an sed command line.
It allows
`sed -i filename -e "expression" AnotherFileName`
which is an unintentionally camouflaged version of
`sed -i'NoExtensionGiven' "expression" filename AnotherFileName`.

Answer (score 104):

For support on both OSX and Linux, I use a simple if check to see if the bash script is running on OSX or Linux, and adjust the command's `-i` argument based on that.

```sh
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
  sed -i '' -e 's|$iconPath|images-theme-dark/$iconfile|g' "{}"
else
  sed -i -e 's|$iconPath|images-theme-dark/$iconfile|g' "{}"
fi
```

Comment: The Linux nomenclature works w/ msys too on Windows. Thanks for the tip Acidic.

Answer (score 11):

In my bash scripts I use something like that (to support both MacOS and Linux distributions):

```sh
SEDOPTION=
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
  SEDOPTION="-i ''"
fi

sed $SEDOPTION "/^*/d" ./file
```

Comment: Please explain the additional insight this provides on top of existing answers, especially the one by @Acidic9. I fail to see the functional difference between your answer and that one. Also, "I use something like this" provides no explanation to this otherwise code-only answer. In short please make your contribution more obvious, to avoid the impression of having copied and minimally, functionally irrelevantly, changed it.

Comment: storenth's answer is more portable and becomes increasingly better the more sed commands you are using, though I needed the `-i` option for non-macOS.  That said, this solution had a weird quirk on my macOS by appending the quotation marks from `$SEDOPTION` to the filename.  I had to resort to the following hackery to prevent that... I tried many other things like piping xargs, swapping single and double quotes, backticks, etc. but this is what worked for me (`\x27` represents single-quote):

`if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then SEDOPTION='-i \x27\x27'; else SEDOPTION='-i'; fi;`

Comment: This assumes that sed is that of base macOS, and can break if not (for instance if sed comes from MacPorts). A bulletproof solution is more complicated (checking the path of sed might not be enough…).

Answer (score -6):

For me, it got fixed by restarting

```
wsl --shutdown
```