# Not getting replaced using the sed using the sed -i command

Tags: linux, reactjs, sed

I am trying to do the following thing using the sed

```
 cp src/config/template.js src/config/index.js

export API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9000/"

sed -i "" "s|{{API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT}}|$API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT|g" src/config/index.js
```

But when I run this script, then I am getting this error,

```
sed: can't read s|{{API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT}}|http://localhost:9000/|g: No such file or directory
```

I am using a Linux machine.

Can any tell me why this is happening?

Comment: remove `""` after `-i`, it is treated as sed script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sed gives: sed: can't read : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43171648/608639)

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to sed should be the script. So when you have that extra `""`, the second argument is interpreted as a file name.

And you don't need to copy the file and then do an inplace replacement. Instead use `>` operator to redirect the output from sed to the proper file.

```
>src/config/index.js <src/config/template.js sed "s|{{API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT}}|$API_GATEWAY_ENDPOINT|g"
```