# How can I make Jenkins execute a sed command inside a script containing both ' and " inside

Tags: shell, jenkins, sed

I need Jenkins to run a shell script named `create_environment.sh` including the following command:

```
sed -i '' "s~variable \"backendPoolID\" { default = \".*\"~variable \"backendPoolID\" { default = \"$backend_address_pool_id\"~g" var.tf
```

When I run the script inside the `Jenkins` machine it works without a problem, but inside the Jenkins pipeline I get the Error:

```
sed: can't read s~variable "backendPoolID" { default = ".*"~variable "backendPoolID" { default = ""~g: No such file or directory
```

**The pipeline step:**

```
steps {
          withCredentials([azureServicePrincipal('xxxx')]) {
            dir("${WORKSPACE}/azure/terraform/deployment/${params.AZURE_ENV}") {
              echo " *************************** Deploy /${params.AZURE_ENV} ***************************** "
              sh "chmod 777 *"
              sh "./create_environment.sh"
              echo " *************************** Deploy erfolgreich ***************************** "
            }
```

I already tried to replace sh `"` with sh `"""`, but it didn´t helped.

Do anyone have some experience with that?

Comment: Try replacing `-i ''` with `-i''`, or just remove `''`

Comment: Thank you, it did help! By removing ' ' I could additionally rewrite the sed command to a much simpler one.

Comment: It is a duplicate of [Sed gives: sed: can't read : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171648/sed-gives-sed-cant-read-no-such-file-or-directory)