# Performing a recursive find and replace with sed only changes first file

Tags: macos, sed, find, exec, xargs

I am trying to recursively search the current directory, performing a sed replace on the first line of each `.txt` file found.

Running either of these 2 commands, on MacOS:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i '' '1 s/([^()]*)//g' {} +
```

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' '1 s/([^()]*)//g'
```

leads to the same result. Only the "first" file found has the `sed` operation performed on it. This appears to be because of the `1` in `sed -i '' '1 s/([^()]*)//g'`. The weird thing is that even though this causes only the first file to be used, it also still only performs the sed replace on the first line of this file; which it should.

If I change the command to this

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' '2 s/([^()]*)//g'
```

it is still only the first file that is changed, but now the second line has the replacement. My question, then, is why does this only appear to affect the first file returned by

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0
```

**Edit for Clarification**

I should clarify what exactly I mean by only the "first" file has the sed operation performed on it by recreating the problem step by step. First,

This is the folder hierarchy (note the space in "folder 1"):

```
.
├── folder\ 1
│   └── test1.txt
├── folder2
│   └── test2.txt
├── folder3
│   └── test3.txt
└── folder4
    └── test4.txt
```

Each `.txt` file contains exactly this, and only this, one line:

`This should stay (this should go)`

When running either of the commands above, it is the file `test2.txt` that is changed, and the problem is that it is the only file that is changed!

So now, the files contain the following:

*test1.txt*: `This should stay (this should go)`

*test2.txt*: `This should stay`

*test3.txt*: `This should stay (this should go)`

*test4.txt*: `This should stay (this should go)`

I believe this is because the first part of the command, for example

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0
```

gives the following (each separated by a `\0` null character)

```
./folder2/test2.txt./folder3/test3.txt./folder4/test4.txt./folder 1/test1.txt
```

By changing the folder and file names around randomly, it is clear that it is always the first file in the above `\0` delimited list that is changed.

So the question remains, what is it about the call to sed that prevents it being called on ALL of the files?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think the `''` does? Did you check in your seds help? What happens if you remove it?  Which sed are you using, MacOs, GNU?

Comment: @Yunnosch I thought the ‘’ was necessary to prevent MacOS from creating backup copies of the edited files? So by using ‘’ I forced sed to edit each file as is

Comment: Double check in the help or docu. The `-i` syntax is at least different between MacOs and GNU. And there are some nasty traps, especially when combined with `-e` (which you did not use, I know). Double check the whole command line. But I am not trying to seem wise, your question puzzles me. I just mention the worst thinkgs I have learned concerning sed.

Comment: Compare this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43171648/sed-gives-sed-cant-read-no-such-file-or-directory/43453459#43453459 (yes one of mine...) describing the possibility to read `''` as "a file the name of which is the empty string". I do not see how this answers your question, but it probably is worth triple checking to not be involved. I do not have access to a MacOs sed, that is why I am wildly proposing things to try and read.

Comment: If I got you right that you use MacOs sed, then I recommend to [edit] and explicity mention that in your question. Try to also find a tag to reflect that.

Comment: What is the meaning of the `+` at the end of the first command? I think if you use `\;` instead, it will work as intended. I'm not sure why the `xargs` versions don't work.

Comment: @Beta I will have to look in to the why, but that actually worked! Please provide this an answer, and if you want a little explanation, and I'll green tick it. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, but I won't post it as an answer until I *can* explain why it works. I have a partial answer to the `xargs` riddle...

Comment: @Beta: For the `+` in place of (escaped) `;`, see POSIX [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html). It means "one or more files" (similar to `+` in an ERE, extended regular expression) until the argument list is too long. It also means you don't need [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html), and you don't get plagued by `xargs` default rule that 'if no file names are read, the command is still executed once'. GNU `xargs` provides `-r` to override that default; POSIX doesn't provide a mechanism to override the default.

Comment: See GNU [`xargs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html) for options, including `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty`.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that the line numbers in `sed` are cumulative across the entire set of files edited.  There's only one line `$` — that's the last line of the last file.  There's only one line `1` — that's the first line of the first (non-empty) file.  That explains the results you're observing.  The fix is to run a separate `sed` for each file.  You can replace the `+` at the end of the `find` with `\;` (or `';'` or `";"`) so it executes the `sed` command for each file.  If the choice is between 'slow but correct' and 'fast but wrong', choose 'slow but correct'.

Comment: NB: POSIX `xargs` provides `-n number` which executes the command with up to _number_ arguments (subject to length limits) but with the caveat _The last iteration has fewer than number, but not zero, operands remaining._ So, POSIX `xargs` won't execute the command with 0 arguments if you specify `-n 1000`. The macOS `xargs` behaves like that automatically (even without `-n`); the GNU `xargs` adheres to POSIX and executes the command once with no file names if `-n` (or `-r`) is not given. The POSIX rule is silly but backwards compatible with some ancient version of `xargs`. That's unfortunate!

Comment: @Yunnosch: The GNU `sed` takes an optional suffix to `-i` but that must be attached to the option, so `-i` on its own means "no backup suffix" (and hence no backup), while `-i.bak` means "use `.bak` as the backup suffix".  The macOS `sed` requires a suffix (it is _not_ optional), but the empty suffix must be in a separate argument. Hence `-i .bak` means "use `.bak` as the backup suffix" and `-i ''` or `-i ""` means no backup. If a script must be portable between GNU and macOS, then you must use `-i.xyz` with the chosen suffix attached to the `-i` argument. There is no portable in-place option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the question about the 1st command is answered by Beta and let me answer the 2nd one.

Try to put `-t` (test) option to `xargs` and see how the command line
is expanded:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -t sed -i '' '1 s/([^()]*)//g'
```

It will output something like:

```
sed -i '' 1 s/([^()]*)//g ./test1.txt ./test2.txt ./test3.txt ./test4.txt
```

The default behavior of `xargs` is to execute the specified command
(`sed` in this case) at once with the all arguments read from the standard
input.
In addition `sed` doesn't reset line numbering across multiple input files and the `s` command
above will be applied for the 1st file only.

You can change the behavior of `xargs` with `-l1` option:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -l1 -t sed '1 s/([^()]*)//g'
```

Output:

```
sed -i '' 1 s/([^()]*)//g ./test1.txt
sed -i '' 1 s/([^()]*)//g ./test2.txt
sed -i '' 1 s/([^()]*)//g ./test3.txt
sed -i '' 1 s/([^()]*)//g ./test4.txt
```

Then `sed` will work as expected.